# select time range issue

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm having a weird issue using the FullCalendar JQuery Plugin. Everything works fine except when i'm in the "week" view, when I choose a time slot, it seems to automatically choose the slot 30-60 minutes greater than what I want to choose.

For exampl, if I want to select 3 PM slot, when I click on the 3 PM slot, it actually highlights either 3:30 or 4 PM Slot.

This is really bothering me and can't figure out how to solve it. I have a feeling that it has to do with some css styling on my side? I do want to point out that I had to change the original width of the calendar from 900 pixels to 100% in order to fit into what I had. Do you think that somehow messed up some calculations related to the offset of the mouseclicks?

Comment: can somebody please help with this?

Answer (score 1):

It´s been almost a year since You posted this, but just in case someone else is searching for a similar issue I found this in the fullcalendar issue tracker:

http://code.google.com/p/fullcalendar/issues/detail?id=1035&q=select&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars

It basically changes this line(3152) in fullcalendar.js:

`slotHeight = slotTableFirstInner.height() + 1; // +1 for border`

for this one:

`slotHeight = slotTableFirstInner.parents('tr').outerHeight() + 1; // +1 for border`

This didn´t totally works for me cuase in the latest hours in day view was selecting 30 minutes less, but taking out the " + 1" did the trick, this is what works for me:

`slotHeight = slotTableFirstInner.parents('tr').outerHeight();`

Hope this help someone out there!